# Having trouble with function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function to check if a list matches a condition, and if it does, it prints that value twice. However, in ghc it gives me an error, and i don't understand why...

```
verifyList f xs = foldl(\x acc -> if f x then x:x:acc else acc) [] xs
```

Any Help?

Comment: "However, in ghc it gives me an error" - What error would that be?

Comment: @bheklilr " No instance for (Num [a0]) arising from a use of ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it"

Comment: Looks like you meant `foldr` instead of `foldl`.  If I make that change then it works for me.

Comment: You could also have done this without `fold`s as `verifyList f xs = concatMap (\x -> [x, x]) $ filter f xs`, which I would say more clearly indicates your intent.  First filter the list to find all that satisfy `f`, then duplicate each element.

Comment: ... or the single list comprehension `[y | y<-[x,x], x<-xs, f x]`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's a really pretty way of putting it, but there is a bit of an error there. You need `x` to be in scope before you use it. Also, you should move the `f x` earlier so it doesn't check it twice for each. `[y | x <- xs, f x, y <- [x,x]]` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like you meant `foldr` instead of `foldl`. If I make that change then it works for me.
>
> You could also have done this without folds as
>
> ```
> verifyList f xs = concatMap (\x -> [x, x]) $ filter f xs
> ```
>
> which I would say more clearly indicates your intent. First filter the list to find all that satisfy `f`, then duplicate each element.

–  bheklilr

Another option based on a comment by leftaroundabout:

```
verifyList f xs = [y | x <- xs, f x, y <- [x, x]]
```

My own spin on bheklilr's approach, because I feel like it:

```
verifyList f xs = filter f xs <**> [id, id]
```